Enable preview tab is not working in intellij 2023
Whenever i try to click an inside class from a main file it opens in a same tab. For example I have a class A and inside it it has references of class B and class C.Whenever i click on class B it replaces class A instead of opening it from a new tab.This is annoying to me.
I tried unchecking Enable preview tab in intellij 2023 but its not working.
Can you suggest if anythning is missing here

Any chance you have turned off tabs? (Tab placement = None) If so, turn them back on (Tab Placement = Top)

this is not the issue. The issue is it overrides the new tab if that new class is open from within the already opened class.

Does the number of open tabs equal the Tab limit? (You can find the tab limit in Settings | Editor | Editor Tabs, under Closing Policy). If not, a screenshot might help understand the problem.

Otherwise, check  whether "Open declaration source in the same tab" is enabled. You can find it in Settings | Advanced Settings, under Editor Tabs.

Ya that worked. thanks

Check whether "Open declaration source in the same tab" is enabled. You can find it in Settings | Advanced Settings, under Editor Tabs
